# jQuery: running success in 1.3.2 but not in 1.4.2

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.3, jquery-1.4

Nothing is wrong, as soon as i change the lib to 1.3.2 my on success stuff works just fine? How comes? Not even the alert with TEST appears..

Here's the code this is happening on:

```
function crop() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url:"functions.php?action=crop",
        data: 
        {
            x: $('#x').val(),y: $('#y').val(),w: $('#w').val(),
            h: $('#h').val(),fname:$('#fname').val(),fixed:fixed,
            sizew:sizew,sizeh:sizeh},
            success: function(response)
            {
                alert('TEST');
                if(!fixed) // Missing { }
                { 
                    $("#showPhoto").css({overflow:"auto"}); // Missing ;
                }
                $("#showPhoto").html(
                    $(document.createElement("img")).attr(
                        "src",response.filename)).show();

                $("#showPhoto").after("There you go...").show();
                $("#image").slideUp();
           },
          error:function(response) {
                   console.log('error: ', response);
               }
        });
    }
```

How can i make it to work with jquery 1.4.2 library?

Comment: How is this different from your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639317/jquery-whats-up-with-the-success

Comment: fixed is a var fixed = 1; if the image have fixed size..

Comment: @patrick dw, i know the main problem now, and want it to work with 1.4.2. In the other question i wanted to know what the problem is, but now i know and want to solve it

Comment: @Karem: If you know the problem, then what is it?

Comment: @Guffa I dont know the problem i mean the issue and that the script only support the old library for some reason, that i DONT know what is

Comment: @Karem - what does your JSON response look like? My money's on it not being valid JSON :)

Comment: @Nick Craver: looks like this:
 ({"filename":"images\/profilePhoto\/thumbs\/1283596240.jpg"})   - I dont know why the / has turned \/ ,  but it do still work fine with 1.3.2.

Comment: Please check updated question for links for live version of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON coming back isn't valid, the example you posted:

```
({"filename":"images\/profilePhoto\/thumbs\/1283596240.jpg"})
```

And the response I got in the page:

```
({"filename":"1283597560.jpg"})
```

Both aren't valid JSON, you need to remove the `()` wrapper on there.  You can check your JSON response for validity here: http://www.jsonlint.com/

The 1.3.2 vs 1.4.2 difference is that in 1.4.0 jQuery added strict JSON checking, if it's not valid it'll fail (so it can take better advantage of browsers' native JSON parsers).

[From the 1.4 release notes](http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14):

> **Strict JSON parsing, using native JSON.parse**: ([jQuery.ajax() Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), [Commit 1](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/90a87c03b4943d75c24bc5e6246630231d12d933), [Commit 2](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/308d6cdad023da190ace2a698ee4815ed8dad9c5), [Commit 3](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/44e6beb10304789044de2c5a58f5bb82e8321636))
>
> jQuery 1.3 and earlier used JavaScript’s `eval` to evaluate incoming JSON. jQuery 1.4 uses the native JSON parser if available. It also validates incoming JSON for validity, so malformed JSON (for instance `{foo: "bar"}`) will be rejected by jQuery in [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON) and when specifying “json” as the dataType of an Ajax request.